# Inserting list into another list using loops only:

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using the current version of python.  I need to return a copy of list1 with list2 inserted at the position indicated by index i.e if the index value is 2, list2 is inserted into list 1 at position 2. I can only use for/while loops, the range function & the list_name.append (value) methods and the lists cannot be sliced.  So if list1 list1 = boom list2 = red and the index value = 2, how do I return a new list = boredom?  I have this so far:

```
list1 = ['b','o','o','m']
list2 = ['r','e','d']
index = 2
new_list = []

if index > len(list1):
    new_list = list1 + list2
    print (new_list)
if index <= 0:
    new_list = list2 + list1
    print (new_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to Padriac's - using three `for` loops:

```
list1 = ['b','o','o','m']
list2 = ['r','e','d']

n = 2
new_list = []
for i in range(n): # append list1 until insert point
    new_list.append(list1[i])
for i in list2: # append all of list2
    new_list.append(i)
for i in range(n, len(list1)): # append the remainder of list1
    new_list.append(list1[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you hit the index, use an inner loop to append each element from list2:

```
for ind, ele in enumerate(list1):
    # we are at the index'th element in list1 so start adding all
    # elements from list2
    if ind == index:
        for ele2 in list2:
            new_list.append(ele2)
    # make sure to always append list1 elements too      
    new_list.append(ele)
print(new_list)
['b', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'm']
```

If you must use range just replace enumerate with range:

```
new_list = []

for ind in range(len(list1)):
    if ind == index:
        for ele2 in list2:
            new_list.append(ele2)
    new_list.append(list1[ind])
print(new_list)
['b', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'm']
```

Or without ifs using extend and remove if allowed:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(index):
    new_list.append(list1[i])
    list1.remove(list1[i])
new_list.extend(list2)
new_list.extend(list1)
```

Appending as soon as we hit the index means the elements will be inserted from the correct index, the elements from list1 must always be appended after your if check.

Comment: can't use enumerate or dictionaries either - can only use if/elif statements,while/for loops, .append() and range functions - extremely frustrating and limiting - any other suggestions?

Comment: @SMF-01, the second method fulfils all that criteria.

Comment: No worries, you can replace the range with while loops and use similar logic but there are not many other simpler ways to do it with the restrictions you have

Comment: @Padraic well - I've had a go at an alternative version - mind you - it's one line longer - however, doesn't use any `if`s :p - So literally is only `while/for`, `range` and `list.append` :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this small snippet of code I've written.
Check the `while` condition that is used. I hope it will answer your question.

```
email = ("rishavmani.bhurtel@gmail.com")
email_split = list(email)

email_len = len(email)
email_uname_len = email_len - 10

email_uname = []
a = 0
while (a < email_uname_len):
    email_uname[a:email_uname_len] = email_split[a:email_uname_len]
    a = a + 1

uname = ''.join(email_uname)
uname = uname.replace(".", " ")
print("Possible User's Name can be = %s " %(uname))
```